# Import address bar in browser to Excel

Tags: excel, browser

Please tell me if any program or browser resolution, which allows you to automatically copy the address bar in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

With VBA, this sub copy the address bar of the IE application open.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim objWindow As Object
    Dim objIEApp As Object
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objItem As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
    For Each objItem In objWindow
        If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*iexplore*") Then
            Set objIEApp = objItem
        End If
    Next objItem
    Debug.Print objIEApp.LocationURL
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 because you have over 1k rep and a random user name. And also because this seems to be a good solution.